# Polygonscan NFT inventory indexing is not working properly

Tags: etherscan, nft, polygon, erc-1155

There is an ERC-1155 NFT contract deployed to Polygon Mainnet network: `0x057287DF57b9e0E45c250e8fA44115A11DD9E451`

Currently, well over 350 unique NFTs have been minted on this smart contract. However, the [inventory](https://polygonscan.com/token/0x057287DF57b9e0E45c250e8fA44115A11DD9E451#inventory) page only displays 32 unique token IDs, and none of the images are displayed correctly. In contrast, other explorers like [NFTScan](https://polygon.nftscan.com/0x057287df57b9e0e45c250e8fa44115a11dd9e451?module=NFTs) display all the minted tokens and show the images properly.

What steps can I take to resolve the issue?

If I can't resolve it independently, where should I report the NFT indexing problem? I couldn't locate an appropriate place to report the bug on Polygonscan.